# garbled when copy code from ubuntu to windows

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ubuntu

```
1. I work on ubuntu 12.04 and my friend works on win7.
2. It is java project based on maven. 
3. We both use eclipse with UTF-8
```

I archieve my project to project.zip, and send it with email.

```
1. `mvn jetty:run` works fun for him.
2. `mvn jetty:run` not works after `mvn clean`. 
   [error: package com.myproject.xxxx not exist]
```

So, what cause the problem?

Comment: I have seen similar issue when you have two files / folders with same name but different capitalization like `myproject` and `Myproject` both these names will be treated as different on Linux, but on Windows since file names are insensitive, the files / folders will be overwritten on extraction. Hope you are not running into something similar

Answer (score 0):

Right click on file in Eclipse, then properties -> resource - change `text file encoding` to UTF-8

This can also be set as the project or workspace default

Comment: Not work~we both set the eclipse to UTF-8 before I code the project

Comment: It cause the same problem,  change text file encoding to UTF-8 works fine, but still get error after I type mvn clean